# Using Ubuntu without installation

Tags: ubuntu

I have found that sometimes a linux distribution like Ubuntu makes things a whole lot easier to fix. However, this is good for my own computers, where I can just install it and not worry about it anymore.

But is there a way to use Ubuntu onto *someone else's* computer without installing it permanently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could boot ubuntu from a cd and chose the **Try Ubuntu without any changes to your machine** option :)

Answer (score 2):

`A live CD can be used for a quick demo or test of Ubuntu.` Try Ubuntu without any changes to your machine! Windows or whatever you use normally is unaffected after trying this and then rebooting.

The standard Ubuntu Cd can be used as a LiveCd as well as an installer. Live mode is the default option when booting from CD.

Check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) how to use Live CD Session to use Ubuntu without installation. there some linux OS live cd available. Search on Google..

Download from here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download

Answer (score 1):

For computers that support boot from USB, you could put Ubuntu on a flash drive, and boot from that.

You can see instructions and [examples](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/put-ubuntu-10-04-on-flash-drive-using-windows/) at pendrivelinux.com

Answer (score 0):

Just boot off of the CD, and run it "Live"

Answer (score 0):

You can even "install Ubuntu as an application on windows" using [wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide).

The Windows-based Ubuntu Installer (Wubi) allows you to install and uninstall Ubuntu from within Microsoft Windows. It lets a Microsoft Windows user try Ubuntu without risking any data loss due to disk formatting or partitioning.

Now this is funny thing.

1. You can install Ubuntu by double clicking on wubi.exe
2. You can uninstall Ubuntu from Control Panel > Add or Remove Programs" for Windows XP or lower or "Control Panel > Programs and Features" for Windows Vista or Windows 7. Alternatively, you can run: C:\ubuntu\Uninstall-Ubuntu.exe.

Comment: This is great for experimenting on your own computer, but I believe the OP was looking for a portable solution.